# How do I install a 64-bits kernel in my Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit, kernel

I'm running in a machine with a 64bits CPU, but my kernel shows me (when I use uname -m command) that I'm running on 32bits (686). How can I change the kernel version to use all capacity of my machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to download and install the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu.

There is no way to do a direct upgrade from 32-Bit to 64-Bit.

You can get the X86_64 version from the Ubuntu download site [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/GetUbuntu/download)

Comment: I just can't find the X86_64 version, just the amd64, as you can see on this mirror: http://mirror.globo.com/ubuntu/releases/jaunty/

Comment: Same version. X86_64 or AMD64 both refer to 64Bit